# AWS EKS Cluster : InvalidParameterException: Unsupported Kubernetes minor version update ,Terraform Gitlab CI

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab, terraform, amazon-eks

The following errors occur every time I run the pipeline

```
│ Error: error updating EKS Cluster (business-staging) version: InvalidParameterException: Unsupported Kubernetes minor version update from 1.19 to 1.18
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "d3203e19-5691-48eb-9442-05435331c8a4"
│   },
│   ClusterName: "business-staging",
│   Message_: "Unsupported Kubernetes minor version update from 1.19 to 1.18"
│ }
│ 
│   with module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/eks/ekcluster.tf line 11, in resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this":
│    11: resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this" {
│ 
╵
```

Do i need to update  control plane to a new Kubernetes version.

what is the issue here , how to solve this, nay suggestion is appricated here .

Comment: Heh, it sure does look like you have the versions swapped, as going `from 1.19 to 1.18` is for sure not an **upgrade**. Also, AWS stopped supporting [1.19 in August, 2022](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html#kubernetes-release-calendar) so that's likely making your situation worse

Answer (score 0):

EKS does not allow downgrades, you need to create a new cluster with the previous version. And well, as said before, the version 1.18 is deprecated so you won't be able to use it.